# HP 255 G8 reboot randomly

Tags: drivers, kernel, hardware, reboot

My laptop keep crashing randomly with Kubuntu 21.10 . The Cpu temp are usually low and the battery have 100% health.
Here are the results of sudo dmesg --level=err:

```
[    0.326126] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.WLBU._STA.WLVD],
AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
[    0.326149] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WLBU._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
[    0.397052] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.WLBU._STA.WLVD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
[    0.397087] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WLBU._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
[    0.464498] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.WLBU._STA.WLVD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
[    0.464536] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WLBU._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
[    0.536763] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.WLBU._STA.WLVD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
[    0.536806] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WLBU._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
[    3.943042] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20211217/dsopcode-133)
[    3.944006] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WHCM due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20211217/psparse-529)
[    3.944026] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20211217/psparse-529)
[    4.195826] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20211217/dsopcode-133)
[    4.195859] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WHCM due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20211217/psparse-529)
[    4.195866] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20211217/psparse-529)
```

Comment: Update UEFI before any further troubleshooting.

Comment: Uefi is updated at the latest version (F25 is the last version on HP site)

Comment: I've been speaking with hp, and the only answer is install windows 10/11 and install oficials drivers. In my case that problem happen with ubuntu 20.04 , ubuntu 20.04.01 , and a Manjaro version which i don't remeamber